# path variable: removing unwanted items

Tags: path, registry, variables, cmd

background info;

an application is installed on many different PCs, W2000 and XP pro and for multiple users, let's call it foobar, note there is no msi or silent uninstall for this app. therefore, we would like to remove its' entry manualy;

If in the registry environment (path line) we have path=c:\windows;c:\windows\system32;c:\foobar\bin;c:\foobar\bat;c:\c:\oracle\bin

how would we, from the command line, change that line to path=c:\windows;c:\windows\system32;c:\c:\oracle\bin

each path line might be different but c:\foobar\bin;c:\foobar\bat; has to be deleted on all machines.

My thought,

export registry env setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment and remove the unwanted items from there and reimport.  Easier solution??

Answer (score 0):

To permanently change the PATH use

Control Panel, System, Environment, System Variables
Control Panel, System, Environment, User Variables